# MySQL: Indexing for a WHERE clause with multiple BETWEEN expressions

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, between

On a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (..., k1 INTEGER, k2 INTEGER)
```

I would like to index for a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (k1 BETWEEN @a AND @b) AND (k2 BETWEEN @x AND @y)
```

It seems to me that creating a BTREE index on (k1, k2) should do the trick, but EXPLAIN says otherwise.  It says that it will use a key_len of 4 to match for k1, but it doesn't really benefit when matching for k2 (other than having narrowed things down in the table somewhat.  But if k1's range is wide, then there's still a lot of work to do constraining for k2).

And one MySQL Performance Blog article may indicate that it shouldn't because once the interval range is utilized, it just scans for the rest: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/

Is there any other indexing scheme or multiple table scheme that can make this query optimal?

I thought to use partitioning where I would partition on k1.  The docs say that the optimizer takes this into account.  If I created many partitions, and the data was fairly distributed, then things the linear scans would be better if the engine only has to access a small number of partitions.  But, A) Partitioning isn't enabled on my particular mysql server and I don't have rights to change that  and B) I actually have 3 BETWEEN statements in my actual application.  So partitioning would only help the first BETWEEN expression with still two to go.

It seems like this would be a fairly common situation that would arise and be in need of indexing, but I haven't much seen the question asked quite in this way out there.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: MySQL is not really known for its query optimization.

Comment: I know.  That's why I'm trying to optimize it. :)

Comment: Optimiser has option to use index or do a full scan, if it thinks that scan will be faster. It is done based on statistics. If you could provide us with output of `EXPLAIN` as it and using `INDEX` hint to use your (k1,k2) index.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, with a standard B-tree search, you can search *one* column in a range predicate (`BETWEEN` counts as a range predicate, as do `<`, `>`, `!=`, `IN()`, `LIKE`, or `IS [NOT] NULL`).

So your column `k1` benefits from the index, and then the second column really can't benefit from the index. You can see the effect of this in the `key_len` field of EXPLAIN. It will only use a portion of the index, corresponding to the size of the `k1` data type, not both `k1` and `k2`.

MySQL 5.6 improves the optimizer with a new feature called *index condition pushdown*. This means that after the index narrows down the search given `k1`, the remaining search terms are passed to the storage engine, so at least not *all* the rows need to be scanned by the SQL engine. The storage engine can pre-filter them.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html for more details on ICP in MySQL 5.6.

See also my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).